# unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm attempting to put a slider on every page within a theme, however, I wish to change a single page to have a different slider alias for alternative content. the php validator I'm using gives me an unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) on line 3. I'm not sure why that is as my understanding of any code is limited. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php
        if (is_page ('145') {
                    echo do_shortcode ('[rev_slider alias='hp']');
        } else {
                    echo do_shortcode ('[rev_slider alias='main']')
        }
```

Comment: you're missing a closing parentheses in the `if` condition

Comment: Also, those strings in the call to `do_shortcode` are wrong.

Comment: And you need a semicolon at the end of the second `echo`

Comment: In summary, many small mistakes which any decent IDE would point out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has many small mistakes. It should be like:-

```
<?php
    if (is_page ('145')) {
        echo do_shortcode ('[rev_slider alias="hp"]');
    } else {
        echo do_shortcode ('[rev_slider alias="main"]');
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 if (is_page ('145') {
                        echo do_shortcode ("[rev_slider alias='hp']");
            } else {
                        echo do_shortcode ("[rev_slider alias='main']")
            }
```

Comment: You've tried to use the comments to fix the problems but have missed certain comments.

Comment: we both put the solution same time, even after i see that comment i review as useful.  i don't care about your review.

Comment: You have misunderstood my comment, you answer is still incorrect. You have syntax errors, no need to get so worked up.